# What is the best practice to add const to an existing interface in PHP?

Tags: php, symfony, interface

I am working with Symfony2's VoterInterface to implement [voters](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/voters.html) for determining user access.

The interface declares three const variables:

```
interface VoterInterface
{
    const ACCESS_GRANTED = 1;
    const ACCESS_ABSTAIN = 0;
    const ACCESS_DENIED  = -1;
...
```

I would like to add a fourth called ACCESS_READONLY for read only access but as far as I am aware it is not possible to "inherit" an interface in PHP.

I don't think it is a good idea to change the interface as it is part of Symfony2's vendor library. An option would be to copy the interface into my own namespace and make the modification. However I'd appreciate input on a better way to get this done.

Comment: I'm not sure that voters are the appropriate place to determine the TYPE of access granted, rather than simply whether access SHOULD be granted. Have you looked into the [ACL system](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html), which can manage different access levels for a resource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you not extend an interface. For example.

```
interface abc extends VoterInterface
{
    const ACCESS_READONLY = 1;
}
```

And then implement abc. I have not tried it but maybe worth a shot.

Comment: Yes you can! Somehow I missed that in the docs and I thought it wasn't a feature in PHP. Example 3 on http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php.